# Using VisibilityDetector is there a good way to determine when a widget is some % distance from the bottom of the screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

Im playing with `VisibilityDetector` and it looks quite powerful it what it can do.  But I'm wondering if there is a reliable way to detect when a given widget is some % from the bottom of the screen, or better yet when the bottom margin of a given widget is some % from the bottom of the screen?

Comment: `VisibilityDetector` currently isn't able to do that; I specifically designed it to fire callbacks only if the widget's visibility actually changed.  If you really wanted, you could fork the code and try modifying `VisiblityDetectorLayer._fireCallback` to remove the `matchesVisibility` check.  I don't remember offhand if it will still be triggered when the widget is fully onscreen when repositioned, though.

Comment: @jamesdlin ok thanks, will attempt to do it.   I think Im looking for a hybrid between VisibilityDetector and ScrollablePositionedList listeners

Answer (score 0):

A Flutter package that builds a ListView or CustomScrollView and notifies when the widgets are on screen within a provided area.

https://pub.dev/packages/inview_notifier_list
try this packages